# Is it helpful to set the variable and object to null?

Tags: java, android, performance, object, null

I would like to optimize my code, and have a little question. If I do this:

```
TextView currentConsole = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Mainactvt_currentConsole);
String currentConsoleName = currentConsole.getText().toString();
currentConsole = null;
FloatingActionButtonClickEvent(currentConsoleName);
```

Is to set objects to null a good way, or is it useless?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: What is your intended purpose of setting object to null ?

Comment: @SamuelKerrien I would know if this is a way to optimize the code. Is this useless because it is garbage collected?

Comment: If your Application stays in that scope for a long time and you do not need the Object thereafter, this could be an optimization of memory usage if the Object is really really mega huge. Otherwise just let it go out of scope and it will be gc-ed unless there are other references to the same object.

Comment: If the situation described by @Fildor is the case, your variable scope is probably too large anyway. Manually nulling out variables is nearly always just extra complication in your code for no benefit.

Comment: @Fildor Perfect, thanks for the Explanation!

Comment: I second @chrylis : nulling has very rare usecases where it should be done.

Comment: In this code snippet it is not helpful, since the GC collects `currentConsole` at the end of its scope, regardless of its current value and the `TextView` "returned" by `findViewById(R.id.txt_Mainactvt_currentConsole)` won't be collected anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collector tracks references to you objects, and when there are no pointer to a certain object it is marked for deletion. It is no deleted immediately. So when you write `currentConsole = null;` you just tell gc that the console object should be deleted and it will be on the next garbage collection.

To optimize you can call `System.gc();` this will trigger collection, but the gc might chose to ignore it so there is no guarantee that the console object will be delete after the null assignment.

The garbage collection interval is calculated in run-time depending mainly on the number of objects and the frequency of new allocations, so the best thing you can do is let the GC do its job, in most cases he does the best thing.

And finally about null assignments in general, yes they are useful in rare cases, consider this code

```
void testGCMethod()
{
    //Create very big object
    VeryBigObjectType o = new VeryBigObjectType();
    //do dometinh with o
    o.someMethod();

    //Do something that takes long time to complete that doesn't involve o
    Thread.sleep(1000 * 1000 * 1000);
}// end of method meaning the o pointer has just been freed and the big object has just been marked for deletion.
```

So in this case (if the JIT doesn't rearrange the code) the VeryBigObjectType instance will be kept the whole time in memory, so some developers like to assign o to null so that is collected as soon as possible by the GC

```
void testGCMethod()
{
    //Create very big object
    VeryBigObjectType o = new VeryBigObjectType();
    //do dometinh with o
    o.someMethod();
    o=null;


    //Do something that takes long time to complete that doesn't involve o
    Thread.sleep(1000 * 1000 * 1000);
}// end of method meaning the o pointer has just been freed and the big
```

This way the big object will be deleted (probably) before the Thread.sleep and save some memory;

Comment: Even though this looks correct it won't affect OPs code, because the TextView won't be removed by the GC, since the internals of the app will still hold a reference to it (since it needs to display it).

Comment: Yes you are right, in my example,about the null,  I was talking about the general case, not the particular one, but yes in his case the null doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yep, I know, I just wanted to note that in OPs case it doesn't help :P. The answer itself isn't wrong.